# ls and xargs to output specific file extentions

Tags: ls, xargs

I am trying to use `ls` and `xargs` to print specific file extensions `.bam and .vcf` witout the path. The below is close but when I `|` the two `ls` commands I get the error below. Separated it works fine except each file is printed on a newline (my actual data has hundreds of files and make it easier to read).  Thank you :).

**files in directory**

```
1.bam
1.vcf
2.bam
2.vcf
```

**command with error**

```
ls /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/test/R_folder/*.bam | xargs -n1 basename | ls /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/test/R_folder/*.vcf | xargs -n1 basename >> /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/test/log
xargs: basename: terminated by signal 13
```

**desired output**

```
1.bam 1.vcf
2.bam 2.vcf
```

Comment: Just give the arguments to the first ls. You can't just pipe commands however you like. ls *.a *.b *.c ...

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen if you make that an answer I will accept it... thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pipe output into `ls` and have it print that with its other output. You should give the parameters to the first one and it will output everything.

ls *.a *.b *.c | xargs ...q

Answer (score 0):

`ls` isn't really doing anything for you currently, it's the shell that's listing all your files. Since you're piping `ls`'s output around, you're actually vulnerable to [dangerous file names](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

`basename` can take multiple arguments with the `-a` option:

```
basename -a "path/to/files/"*.{bam,vcf}
```

To print that in two columns, you could use `printf` via `xargs`, with `sort` for... sorting. The `-z` or `-0` flags throughout cause null bytes to be used as the filename separators:

```
basename -az "path/to/files/"*.{bam,vcf} | sort -z | xargs -0n 2 printf "%b\t%b\n"
```

If you're going to be doing any more processing after printing to columns, you may want to replace the `%b`s in the `printf` format with `%q`s. That will escape non-printable characters in the output, but might look a bit ugly to human eyes.